# Connecting a multi meter across a single resistor

Tags: resistors, multimeter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foBYjM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I connect a multi meter to AB it shows 5V, but isn't the resistor supposed to decrease the voltage/current? V=IR (5 = I*1000) shows barely any current is going through the resistor but how is that possible?

If I add anything else to the circuit (like an LED or another resistor) then the displayed multi meter values make more sense.

Comment: it reduces the voltage from 5v to 0v, and reduces the current from infinity to 5ma. It might make more intuitive sense to put 10 100-ohm resistors in series and poke around with your voltmeter on that chain.

Comment: it reduces the voltage from 5v to 0v? I don't understand.

Comment: put the meter's black lead on gnd. measure before and after the resistor. it should read 5v before and 0v after; a loss of 5v.

Comment: i mean yes, its also the same as just touching the leads together, of course it shows zero. i'm supposed to measure volt across a component, what you said measures a single peice of wire.

Comment: in the simulator, there's 4 possible test points, and 2 of them are the same at the other two when you only have 2 parts: a source and a load. In the real world, the bottom of the resistor would read something like 0.0013v (give or take some 0s based on the wire thickness and length), while measuring ground is really 0; which is, as you say, touching the leads together. Also the top of the resistor would be slightly under 5v and the supply+ would be 5.000...v. It's just confusing in the simulator with it's perfect (mathematically impossible) wiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> isn't the resistor supposed to decrease the voltage/current?

Ask yourself "decrease the voltage in relationship to what?" Working with vague ideas will lead to confusion, so make them precise.

Notice that the multimeter that is across R1 is also across V1. And what is the voltage across V1? Well it is also 5V. Coincidence? Not really. The voltage drop across the resistor has to match the voltage "lift" (i.e. EMF) by the voltage source.

> V=IR (5 = I*1000) shows barely any current is going through the resistor

5 mA, actually. In some contexts, that might be "barely any current". In other contexts it is not. In this context, it is just what Ohm's law predicts.

Comment: I see, so since multi metre is also connected to the power source directly it's as if the resistor doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Dan The resistor determines the current through that circuit. If you replaced the resistor by an infinite resistance, there would be no current. But there would still be the 5V.

Comment: because the volt meter is directly connected to the source anyways?

Comment: The volt meter isn't responsible for the 5 V, it only let's us measure it. So the 5 V isn't there "because the volt meter is connected".  The 5V is there because there is a 5V source in your schematic.